# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system can't find the specified file

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm currently learning how to use the module `subprocess` and I just started with my new book. Instantly, I got an error message which I don't understand.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/me/Python/subprocess.py", line 3, in <module>
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'Hello there'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system can't find the specified file
```

I couldn't figure out **what is wrong here**:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'Hello there'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
print(out.decode('utf-8'))
```

In the book they said this code should print 'Hello there' on the screen but for some reason, it doesn't.

What is wrong here? I'm currently using python 3.4.3, if that helps you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`echo` is not a program that can be executed but it’s a shell command available in the Windows command line interpreter `cmd.exe`.

In order to execute shell commands, you need to pass `shell=True` to `Popen`:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'Hello there'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
#                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^
```