# Python multithreading multiple bash subprocesses. BUT with setting an environmental variable?

Tags: python, multithreading, bash, subprocess, environment-variables

*Once again programming dos batch commands with Python*

There's a great answer to **[Python threading multiple bash subprocesses?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14533902/2327328)**

I was pretty sure this would solve my problem, but I've tried both the `Popen` and the `multiprocessing` methods and neither works.

Here's my problem: I want to set a unique value for a Windows environmental variable (like `TMP`) that is used in each process. So process 1 will write to folder 1 and process 2 will write to folder 2 - and in terms of environmental variables, process 1 won't see what process 2 sees.

Here's my code based on the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14533902/2327328). Variant 1 uses Windows `set VAR=abc method`. Variant 2 uses Python's `os.environ['TMP']=abc` method, and shouldn't work because TMP is accessed by python before it is set by dos. Neither 1 nor 2 works. Variant 3 is a sanity check, and works, but doesn't solve my problem

```
from subprocess import Popen
import os

commands = [
   # variant 1: does not work
    'set TMP=C:\\Temp\\1 &&  echo abc1 > %TMP%\\1.log', 'set TMP=C:\\Temp\\2 &&  echo abc2 > %TMP%\\2.log' 

   # variant 2: does not work
   # 'set TMP=C:\\Temp\\1 &&  echo abc1 > '+os.environ['TMP']+'\\1.log', 'set TMP=C:\\Temp\\2 &&  echo abc2 > '+os.environ['TMP']+'\\2.log'

   # variant 3: works, but does not set TMP environmental variable
   # 'echo abc1 > C:\\Temp\\1\\1.log', 'echo abc2 > C:\\Temp\\2\\2.log'
]

# run in parallel
processes = [Popen(cmd, shell=True) for cmd in commands]
# do other things here..
# wait for completion
for p in processes: p.wait()
```

Here's my code for the `multiprocessing` method (python variable `commands` is defined in the above script):

```
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from subprocess import call
import os

pool = Pool(2) # two concurrent commands at a time
for i, returncode in enumerate(pool.imap(partial(call, shell=True), commands)):
    if returncode != 0:
       print("%d command failed: %d" % (i, returncode))
```

---

(I've also tried `set TMP=\"C:\\Temp\\1\"` with double quotes around the folder)

((Python 2.7.13 64bit on Windows 10))

---

and not related to the answer I reference, I've tried this function:

```
import os
from subprocess import check_output

def make_tmp(tmp_path):

    os.environ['TMP'] = tmp_path
    dos = 'echo '+tmp_path+' > '+os.environ['TMP']+'\\output.log'
    check_output(dos, shell=True)


from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
pool = ThreadPool(2) 

print os.environ['TMP']
path_array = ['\"C:\\Temp\\1\"', '\"C:\\Temp\\2\"']
```

With the following Traceback:

```
Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird.*
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\project11\Dropbox\project11\code_current\dev_folder\google_sheets\test_windows_variables.py", line 32, in <module>
    results = pool.map(make_tmp, path_array)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'echo "C:\Temp\1" > "C:\Temp\2"\output.log' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

* The process can not access the file because it is being used by another process.

---

Also tried [another answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14533789/2327328), no luck.

Comment: You want to update your environment before making your call, and then use the updated environment in `Popen()` as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment

Comment: thanks. I want to modify the os.environ['TMP'] in the process - so I think the answer you reference won't work

Comment: OK, why do you want to do that? To use the updated value in your original program? Because that cannot be done by the use of a subprocess.

Comment: The full python script wraps around a Windows executable that writes a temp file `data.bin` to the TMP folder. I want to run multiple processes of this Windows executable, but they all reference the same TMP folder and `data.bin` file. That's why I want to update TMP for each process.

Comment: I still don't see why you cannot update the environment in your main script and then pass it to the different subprocess calls. You can give a separate copy to each of them, with different values of `TMP`.

Comment: I want the processes/sessions to run in parallel. It would be great if provide an example? Thanks!

Comment: `Popen` takes an `env` argument that lets you specify the environment to use; don't use `set` in the command itself.

Comment: @chepner this works, do you want to add it as an answer so I can accept? Had to add PIPE and shell=True from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36249753/2327328

Comment: @philshem Well, that is what I tried to make you do as well, if you had looked more carefully at the answer I linked to. ;-)

Comment: yes, that would have saved time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working code, thanks to [Chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162094/python-multithreading-multiple-bash-subprocesses-but-with-setting-an-environmen#comment79287516_46162094) AND [JohanL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162094/python-multithreading-multiple-bash-subprocesses-but-with-setting-an-environmen#comment79286422_46162094) comments

```
import subprocess, os

def make_tmp(tmp_path):

    my_env = os.environ.copy()
    my_env['TMP'] = tmp_path
    dos = 'echo '+tmp_path[-1]+' > '+my_env['TMP']+'\\output.log'
    # or run a bat script
    # dos = 'C:\\Temp\\launch.bat'
    subprocess.Popen(dos, env=my_env, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
pool = ThreadPool(2) 

path_array = ['C:\\Temp\\1', 'C:\\Temp\\2', 'C:\\Temp\\3']

results = pool.map(make_tmp, path_array)
```

*note that the path_array has to be existing folders*

Comment: This should not require `subprocess.PIPE` If your use case is only to redirect the output of your command to a certain file you do not need to use a specific environment at all, though. That is better done in Python itself (which, then, would require `subprocess.PIPE`but not `shell=True`).

Answer (score 1):

If your use case is only to capture the output to a file, you can let Python do that for you, by redirecting the command output to a `subprocess.PIPE` and then store the data from Python. This has the advantage that you do not need to use `shell=True` and thereby save yourself a possible vulnerability and an extra process creation. That could be written as:

```
import subprocess, os

def make_tmp(tmp_path):
    dos = ['echo', tmp_path[-1]]
    outfile = os.path.join(tmp_path, 'output.log')
    cmd_proc = subprocess.Popen(dos, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
        f.write(cmd_proc.communciate[0])

from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
pool = ThreadPool(2) 

path_array = ['C:\\Temp\\1', 'C:\\Temp\\2', 'C:\\Temp\\3']

results = pool.map(make_tmp, path_array)
```

*Caveat:* I have not had the time to test above code, so there could be some minor error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually the echo is a test case, and full python script wraps around a Windows executable that writes a temp file data.bin to the TMP folder. I want to run multiple processes of this Windows executable, but they all reference the same TMP folder and data.bin file. That's why I want to update TMP for each process.